# Pascal decimal-point

Tags: pascal, division, decimal-point

could you please help me with my homework? I am just a beginner and know very little about Pascal :(

I am supposed to write a program for division but have special conditions depending on their decimal numbers. The outputs should look something like this:

1. no decimals then 20/5=4  (there can only be the 4; it can't be like 4.00)
2. if decimals then only 1 decimal number 9/4=2.3
3. if the decimal is an infinite of the same number then 1/3=0.(3)

How can I do it?  I was thinking about putting it into an array but I don't know how to find where the decimal point is nor I know how to write the brackets into an output.

Comment: If you can't get started at all, you need to ask your instructor for help. They clearly haven't done their job properly to give you the information you need to complete the assignment. (It's called a "decimal" point, by the way - it's not "demical".)

Answer (score 2):

I can't manage to solve the 3rd point but here is the code for the first 2:

```
Var
   x,y : integer;
   z : real;
Begin
     z := x / y;
     if z = x div y
        then Write(z:4:0) //Write a real var without any decimals
        else Write(z:4:1); //Write a real var with just 1 decimal
End.
```

You'll have to change things around , like reading x and y , but from this code you can almost do your homework .

I'll try to solve the 3rd time , check the answer again after some time.

Answer (score 0):

To solve 3rd point: think about x and y as about a fraction. Here is the basic idea:

1. A:=A/GCD(A,B);B:=B/GCD(A,B)
2. Integer part := A div B; A:=A mod B
3. Non-periodical part: while A mod 2=0 do BEGIN C:=C*2;A:=A div 2; END; while A mod 5=0 do BEGIN C:=C*5;A:=A div 5; END
4. Find M so that A*M=999..999.